# ffmpeg/ffprobe won't detect the language of a WEBvtt (subtitles) file

Tags: ffmpeg, video, language, subtitles

A WEBvtt subtitle file starts with a few header lines, and one of them indicates the language:

```
WEBVTT
Kind: captions
Language: en


00:00:09.977 --> 00:00:11.563
I'd like you to take
a look at this gun.

00:00:12.564 --> 00:00:14.818
It's handcrafted to my
specifications.
```

But ffmpeg won't detect the language. The ffprobe output on the above file makes no mention of it:

```
ffprobe version 4.4.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
[...]
Input #0, webvtt, from 'Star Trek Continues E01 ＂Pilgrim of Eternity＂ [3G-ziTBAkbQ].en.vtt':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Subtitle: webvtt
```

Consequentely, when muxed into a video file, no language is reported for the subtitle streams.

In constrast, MKVToolnix detects the language when reading a webvtt file (although not always perfectly)

Is there a simple solution? I know it's possible to force a language stream by stream, but I'm really looking for an automatic solution.

Comment: IIRC the subtitle stream language is stored in the container (not in the stream itself) and must be specified manually. Audio streams work the same.

Comment: @DanielB You may be right, but ffmpeg is capable to set the language on its own when it can get it from the input. So I wonder why it won't do that here, since the language is the input file header. MKVToolnix grabs the language when importing a WEBvtt file, ffmpeg doesn't...  But the explanation could be that only the first line of the header is standardized, so fmmpeg won't try reading the non-standard part of the header.